# Merge all log files into one

Tags: cron, logging

As you all probably know as developers we sometimes need to deal with logs.

You have PhP error log, laravel debug, mysql, apache, cron outputs etc.

Here's my question, is it possible to merge all logs files into one? Also can you set it to remove the log each day and merge it again? So only fresh data is in the file?

So it would look like this:

//PHP errors

Whatever...

//apache

Whatever...

//cron

Whatever...

Comment: That would be shockingly simple. Possibly challenging question is: would you have it time-stamp sorted in a mixed manner, and if so, what are the, most likely different, time formats to deal with, and where in the lines would the time stamp be located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly for this was the [`rsyslog` daemon](http://www.rsyslog.com/) written. It comes preinstalled with Ubuntu, but it needs some customization to do what you want. It can read from log files and merge them, collect log messages from other systems over the network, and route them to whatever you want. It is very, very powerful. Getting started with it is, however, shockingly simple, as Jacob says.

Follow the configuration examples from the website and have fun.

Comment: Nice, Never heard of it!

Comment: @JacobVlijm If you have a bunch of busy servers, you want one central place to keep an eye on.  So you tie all important log files together with one `rsyslog` daemon, and colour-code the messages according to their urgency. I have a RPi on my desk for that purpose. Nice to play with.

Comment: Sounds absolutely great!

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to merge all logs files into one?

If you want to merge the logs *by datetime stamp*, then try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 /var/log/php/ /var/log/apache2/ /var/log/cron > /var/log/merged.log
```

> Also can you set it to remove the log each day and merge it again?

This simple shell script would do that

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env sh

s4 /var/log/php/ /var/log/apache2/ /var/log/cron > /var/log/merged.log
```

Copy the script to `/etc/cron.daily/merge-logs.sh`. Don't forget to set the script to executable; `chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/merge-logs.sh`.